# JS: Destructure a dictionary and pass it to a function

Tags: javascript, dictionary, destructuring

In Python if you have a function like this:

```
def my_function(param1, param2, param3):
  print (param1, param2, param3)
```

And you have dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {"param1": 1,
           "param2": 2,
           "param3": 3}
```

Then you can destructure a dictionary and pass the values in the dictionary to the function like this:

```
my_function(**my_dict)
```

which basically calls `my_function(1, 2, 3)`

Is there any way you can do this in `javascript`?
I know you can destructure a `list` using `...` but I am not sure how I can desctructure a dictionary. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Alas, no such thing!

Comment: @georg man! you guys are good at googling. I searched for that for a good 15 mins. couldnt find it lol

Comment: That was an easy one ;))

Comment: JavaScript objects are unordered and JavaScript doesn't have named function parameters, so even if it supported that syntax it would not be able to define which argument goes into each parameter position.